# Python Qt5 Running two methods simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, multiprocessing, python-sounddevice

I have a Qt timer that I want to count down while I record (using the sound device package), I'll attach what I have below (I know it is very far off from anything correct). I've been reading up on multiprocessing and threads, and I think the timeout allows for other functions to be ran, but it seems the record function holds while its writing the file, so I am a bit stumped. Any advice helps, thanks!

```
class CountDown(QWidget):


    def __init__(self, name, index):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(name, index)
    
    def initUI(self, name, index):
        self.setWindowTitle("Timer for "+name)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.time_label = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.time_label)
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.setFixedHeight(500)

        # Create a QTimer that updates the time label every second
        timer = QTimer(self)
        self.current_time = 11
        timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.update_time())
        timer.start(1000)  # Update every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)  

        print("START RECORDING" + name)
        self.record(index, name)
        self.show()

    #need to update time and record simultaneously
    def update_time(self):
        # Get the current time and set it on the label
        if(self.current_time==0): 
            self.close()
        self.current_time-=1
        print(self.current_time)
        self.time_label.setText(f"Current Time: {self.current_time}")

    #Takes in name selected from GUI and finds its index to use for audio device-> records for 1 second
    def record(self, index, name):
        #1 Microphone (USB Lavalier Microp, MME (2 in, 0 out)

        # Sample rate:
        fs = 44100
        # Duration of recording:
        seconds = 5
        myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=1, device=index)
        
        # Wait until recording is finished:
        sd.wait()

        print("STOPPED RECORDING" + name)


        # Save as WAV file:
        write(name+".wav", fs, myrecording)
        return name+".wav"
```

Comment: The timer depends on the event loop to be running to trigger, and you don’t return control to the event loop until the record function returns, so the timer can’t trigger until recording is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would reach for `threading` here. Not all of Qt is thread-safe, but if your recording thread does not directly interact with the GUI, There's almost no work necessary:

```py
...
print("START RECORDING" + name)
self.recording_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.record, args = (index, name))
self.recording_thread.start()
self.show()
...
```

It *is* possible to emit signals from a thread, so you can create a slot  (a callback) which can be triggered by the thread. If you start trying to do stuff like `label.setText()` from a thread that's where you get into trouble.

```py
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot #custom signals and slots
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import ...
from PyQt6 ...

import threading

class CountDown(QWidget):

    recording_done = pyqtSignal() #define a signal our thread will emit when done
    
    def __init__(self, name, index):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(name, index)
    
    def initUI(self, name, index):
        self.setWindowTitle("Timer for "+name)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.time_label = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.time_label)
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.setFixedHeight(500)
        self.setLayout(layout) #explicitly set the layout of the main widget rather than rely on parent-child relationship of label

        # Create a QTimer that updates the time label every second
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.current_time = 11
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_time) #you shouldn't need a lambda here, just pass the method
        self.timer.start(1000)  # Update every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)  

        print("START RECORDING" + name)
        self.recording_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.record, args=(index, name))
        self.recording_thread.start()
        
        self.recording_done.connect(self.on_recording_done)
        self.show()

    #need to update time and record simultaneously
    @pyqtSlot()
    def update_time(self):
        # Get the current time and set it on the label
        if(self.current_time==0): 
            self.timer.stop()
        self.current_time-=1
        print(self.current_time)
        self.time_label.setText(f"Current Time: {self.current_time}")
        
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_recording_done(self): #main process will execute this in the main thread when it gets the signal from the recording thread.
        if self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.stop()
        self.time_label.setText("recording done")

    #Takes in name selected from GUI and finds its index to use for audio device-> records for 1 second
    def record(self, index, name):
        #1 Microphone (USB Lavalier Microp, MME (2 in, 0 out)
        fs = 44100
        seconds = 5
        myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=1, device=index)
        sd.wait()
        print("STOPPED RECORDING" + name)
        write(name+".wav", fs, myrecording)
        self.recording_done.emit() #signal the Qt event loop in the main process
        #return name+".wav" #you can't get the return value from a thread. If you need to return some value, send it via signals and slots, or mutate a shared variable.
```

^note: code is untested.. read for changes and understanding.